# Closest thing to an "int" in JS

Tags: javascript, types, integer, simulate

I've been trying mimic a 32 bit signed numbers in JS. 
I am hoping that there is some way to make it act syntactically identical (after initialization of course) to languages like C, C++, Java, etc.

```
let a = ....
...

// Once initalized
a = 4294967296

// Should return true
console.log(a == 0)

a = Math.pow(2, 31)

// Should return false
console.log(a == Math.pow(2, 31))
```

My attempt is below. I think it's pretty close, but I find the `._`, most definately awkward. Are there better ways such data types may be mimiced in JS? (I can also use `Object.defineProperties` on `window`, and get the desired syntax on global objects, not sure if thats the better way)

```js
function int32_t(n) {
 this._value = new Int32Array([n])
 Object.defineProperties(this, {
  _: {
   get: () => this._value[0],
   set: (n) => {
    this._value[0] = n
    return this._value[0]
   },
   configurable: true
  }
 })
}
let a = new int32_t(10);

// Once initalized
a._ = 4294967296

// Should return true
console.log(a._ == 0)

a._ = Math.pow(2, 31)

// Should return false
console.log(a._ == Math.pow(2, 31))
```

Comment: `x | 0` will convert `x` to a 32-bit signed integer from whatever it was before. Is that what you need?

Comment: you can try typescript

Comment: @VLAZ I am looking for a more robust way of simulating the behaviour of "int". Where assigning values to that specific variable, will automatically convert it to an int. Also it'd be nice if it could be modified to work for other data types including "short" and "char".

Comment: Yeah...that would be a problem. I'd suggest looking for a library before writing your own.

Comment: @VLAZ as blz said, there are languages like typescript and dart which can do this, but they need to compile to JS which is not what I'm looking for, and I'm not using node or npm. If there is a library which can do this, I'd be interested in how it's done. But I have yet to find such a library.

Comment: No, TS cannot do that. TS doesn't really offer extra functionality like new datatypes. It can add typings to ensure you aren't passing a string where a number is expected, for example but you can't just get an *integer*, since the types are only there at compile time. You can use opaque types to try and have only integers, for example, or whatever fancy sub-category you want (e.g., GUIDs, or positive even numbers), however that isn't really a *real* category of values you define, just a compile time check that you're passing a GUID to GUID, rather than something else.

Comment: @VLAZ Right, I assume blz was talking about opaque types. But yeah, I don't expect to achieve an actual new datatype in JS, rather just syntactic similarity as highlighted in the post. But this does seem more difficult than expected.

Answer (score 0):

**For anyone looking for a solution**, this is the closest I could get. 
It is most definitely not the most optimal solution since the variables must be globalized, and hopefully it can be improved in future.

```js
function globalInt(destVar) {
  const varName = Object.keys(destVar)[0]
  const globalName = 'fakeInt_' + varName
  window[globalName] = new Int32Array([0]);
  Object.defineProperties(window, {
    [varName]: {
      get: () => window[globalName][0],
      set: (n) => {
        window[globalName][0] = n
        return window[globalName][0]
      },
      configurable: true
    }
  })
}

// Only works for globals
a = 5;

// Initalize
globalInt({a})

// Once initalized
a = 4294967296

// Should return true
console.log(a == 0)

a = Math.pow(2, 31)

// Should return false
console.log(a == Math.pow(2, 31))
```